# How to know which user answered a Jenkins-Pipeline input step?

Tags: jenkins, versioning, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile script that tests for the possibility to perform an SVN merge and then asks the user for the permission to commit the merge.

I would like to know the username that answers the "input" step in order to write it into the commit message.

Is this possibile?

This is what hypothetically I would like to do:

```
outcome = input message: 'Merge trunk into branch?', ok: 'Merge'
echo "User that allowed merge: ${outcome.user}"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `input` step got an optional [`submitterParameter`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#input-wait-for-interactive-input), which allows to specify the key of the returned `Map` that should contain the user who's submitting the input dialog:

> If specified, this is the name of the return value that will contain the ID of the user that approves this input.
>   The return value will be handled in a fashion similar to the `parameters` value.
>   *Type:* String

This looks then as follows:

```java
def feedback = input(submitterParameter: 'submitter', ...)
echo "It was ${feedback.submitter} who submitted the dialog."
```

P.S: If anybody is interested in a full-fledged code snippet returning the user both for positive and negative feedback to the dialog (and timeout as well), I kindly point to [our pipeline library](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/288ec26cee53c4062ed2e987d2f95b39ef289a6b/src/org/typo3/chefci/helpers/JenkinsHelper.groovy#L50-L91).

Comment: On jenkins v2.128:

            def submitter = input(
              message: "Confirm deployment?",
              submitterParameter: 'submitter'
            ); 
            echo "Deployment confirmed by: ${submitter}"

Comment: Was this a question or example code? That you assign the return value of the `input` call _and_ have it as `submitterParameter` makes no sense.

Comment: It is an example code, and yes it does not make sense, thats why I posted it because it works for some unknown reason. If I don't pass the `submitterParameter` (the value does not matter) it does not work. Thats why I was confused why this answer was accepted. Maybe its a bug or they change this in jenkins.

Comment: @AndrzejRehmann's example shows the odd behavior of how return value is handled. Because input is only given `message` and `submitterParameter` , the return value is just a String object with the submitter value. If the input method was called in a way that supplied additional parameters, then the returned value would be a Map instead of a String.

Answer (score 4):

It is not currently possible, for now only entry parameters are returned in the `input step` answer, as mentionned in [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-input-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/input/InputStepExecution.java) :

```java
// TODO: perhaps we should return a different object to allow the workflow to look up
// who approved it, etc?
switch (mapResult.size()) {
case 0:
    return null;    // no value if there's no parameter
case 1:
    return mapResult.values().iterator().next();
default:
    return mapResult;
}
```

If you'd like to restrict which user(s) can approve the input step, you can however use the `submitter` parameter, e.g. :

```java
input message: 'Approve ?', submitter: 'authorized-submitter'
```

**EDIT**

Since January 2017 it is now possible to request additional parameters to be sent. Please see [StephenKing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849847/702954) above.

Comment: It is in the meantime (see my answer) :-)

Comment: Very nice, thank you for the update ! Your answer should now be the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are not asking for any parameters on the input, then adding the submitterParameter kind of worked. It didn't add it as a parameter on the return object, instead, it turned the returned object into a string with the username in it.

```
def feedback = input(submitterParameter: 'submitter')
echo "It was ${feedback} who submitted the dialog."
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the one by StephenKing 2 months before?

Comment: I explained in my answer. The difference is that if you're not using other input parameters then the result is not a map, where you can get submitter from feedback.submitter, but instead the submitter is actually the value in the feedback object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for exceptions if you turn off the `groovy-sandbox`:

```
try {
 'Deploy to production?'

 node {
  sh 'echo deploying'
  }
} catch(e) {
  def user = e.getCauses()[0].getUser()
   echo "Production deployment aborted by:\n ${user}"
}
```

Comment: or you whitelist the method instead of turning off the sandbox.

Comment: using this method you can not get the userid in try block.

Comment: that would retrieve the user who triggered the build, not necessarily the same that filled the input